# Can I mass replace hundreds of references to files in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I have an iPad app and I've recently replaced hundreds of PNG's with JPG's to reduce the project size.  Now Xcode is rightfully complaining that there are 1000's of missing file references.  I can easily select the file, edit its properties and change .png with .jpg and All is Fine.  However I will be an old man when I'm done.

Is there a way to mass replace all missing references in the project?  Or can I mass remove all missing file references so I can re-add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, edit your project file manually, using BBEdit or some other text editor with a search and replace feature.

Right click on the `whatever.xcodeproj` file (which is really a folder), and select `Show Package Contents`, in there, you'll see a `project.pbxproj` file. Edit this file in your editor, and do a search and replace for `png` to `jpg` or whatever. You can get fancy with your search and use a regex to select specific paths if you like, rather than doing every png file. That only matters if you still have some png's in the project.